# Using htaccess to get rid of /index.php link?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can open my site like this:

```
www.mysite.com
```

or like this:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php
```

I want to create a htaccess rule that redirects [www.mysite.com/index.php](http://www.mysite.com/index.php) to     [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). But all my attempts have other side effects. I've tried:

```
Redirect index.php    home.php
RewriteRule    ^index.php?$    home.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^index.php/?$    redirect_to_home.php    [NC,L]
```

But all of these mess up the original index.php call. So it does redirect but then the normal mysite.com link doesnt work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this redirect rule to remove `/index.php` from any path:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

***Explanation:***

- Making `RewriteEngine On` to make the rules work.
- Mentioning condition by `RewriteCond` to `REQUEST_FILENAME` which checks if mentioned file in browser is present.
- Then checking if `THE_REQUEST` which has complete details of request(including URL and GET/POST method) if it has index.php in it.
- Now checking if `REQUEST_URI` is having `index\.php` in requested url, where saving everything before it to temp buffer memory to retrive its value later(basically its domain name).
- Finally in `RewriteRule` to redirect complete URL with index.php to till domain name only as per requirement(R=301 is for permanent redirection on browser side).